# Why Object.class == Class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, oop

I think Object is everyone's ancestor, including Class.
So I think it should be Class.class == Object.
I feel a bit of confused and twisted

Answer (score 10, accepted):

class returns the class (#type) not the ancestor. Objects's class is Class. Class's class is Class. Class is an Object. Truth in advertising: I never learned Ruby, but the Object-Class relation *has* to be the one Smalltalk set forth 30 years ago.

Comment: Metaclasses work differently in Ruby: they get injected into the method lookup chain, thus Ruby doesn't have the two parallel hierarchies of classes and metaclasses, but, as you say, the basics are identical.

Comment: @Jorg: thanks. As soon as I finish my current project I'll pick up on rails and ruby, I've hear so much praise that I'm intrigued :)

Comment: Thank you. I think I'm clear about the relations now. @Jörg_W_Mittag 's information helps, too. That is, classes and Metaclasses are two different but related concepts.

Comment: Yeah but this explanation doesn't really detail the purpose of class Class and why to extend methods to it, presumably so all classes can have class methods, as opposed to objects which are just instances and inherit from Object class.

Answer (score 9):

Class, Object, Module and all other classes are **instances** of a **class** Class :)

Class.class == Module.class == Object.class == Hash.class == Class

Class is also is an Object (like any other object in the system) but it is not **direct** instance of Object, it is an instance of a **derived** class (Class in this case)

Class.superclass.superclass == Object (with Module in the middle)

Object itself is also a class. so Object.class == Class

Class, Module and Object have a circular dependency as they are in the core of the OO model.

Object.class.superclass.superclass == Object

```
=> parent (.superclass)
-> instance-of (.class)
```

[alt text http://www.grabup.com/uploads/b10b2ffa9976953e3d6f88e6fcbf6f28.png?direct](http://www.grabup.com/uploads/b10b2ffa9976953e3d6f88e6fcbf6f28.png?direct)

Comment: The circular dependency works because these are all built-in classes. They are part of the core Ruby runtime and are set up this way at start-up and aren't added on the way you would normally add a class. The runtime has the power to set up the pointers however it wants, and the designer chose to do it this way.

Answer (score 6):

`Object`'s class is `Class` (since `Object` itself is a class), and `Object` is an ancestor of `Class`.

There is a circular reference, it is pretty complex. My personal recommendation, if you don't really need to play with it, don't go there.

Answer (score 5):

This is the way it works in ruby 1.9:

```
Class.class = Class

Class.superclass = Module
Module.class = class
Module.superclass = Object
Object.class = Class
Object.superclass = BasicObject
BasicObject.class = Class
BasicObject.superclass = nil
```